# Proguard Obfuscation Enum Issue

Tags: android, enums, obfuscation, proguard

I have following Enum class in my Java package

```
public enum UIType {
    NATIVE,WEB;
}
```

I have applied following proguard config to keep this enum class

```
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep public enum android.ui.UIType  {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

But when I offuscate my jar file,proguard keeps the UIType enum class but removes both NATIVE,WEB values.

In my obfuscated jar my Enum class looks as follows.

```
public enum UIType {

}
```

As seen above NATIVE,WEB values are removed by proguard :(.It is causing issue in my application since it is not finding those values.

Can somebody please guide me here what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I understand, you ask it to keep the methods *values()* and *valueOf()*, but not the values themselves.

Try

```
-keep public class com.ggg.xxx.Yyy { *; }
```